# WSO2 Micro Integrator Dashboard cannot find Micro Integrator instance

Tags: java, tomcat, wso2, unauthorized, wso2-micro-integrator

I have wso2 environment running as well as wso2 micro integrator, I decided to add micro integrator dashboard here, but for some reason it can't find micro integrator. Writes an error that is on the screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqktr.png)

Below I have provided a full log cutout, and judging by it, we have a 401

```
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,454] DEBUG {RequestAddCookies} - CookieSpec selected: default
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,462] DEBUG {RequestAuthCache} - Auth cache not set in the context
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,463] DEBUG {BasicHttpClientConnectionManager} - Get connection for route {s}->https://****:9164
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,473] DEBUG {DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection} - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,474] DEBUG {MainClientExec} - Opening connection {s}->https://****:9164
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,475] DEBUG {DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator} - Connecting to /****:9164
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,475] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} - Connecting socket to /****:9164 with timeout 0
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,482] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,483] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,483] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} - Starting handshake
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,503] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} - Secure session established
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,504] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,504] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,505] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} -  peer principal: CN=*.****, O=Municipal Enterprise “****”, ST=****, C=UA
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,505] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} -  peer alternative names: [*.****, ****]
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,506] DEBUG {SSLConnectionSocketFactory} -  issuer principal: CN=GoGetSSL RSA OV CA, O=GoGetSSL, L=Riga, C=LV
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,507] DEBUG {DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator} - Connection established ****:57564<->****:9164
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,507] DEBUG {MainClientExec} - Executing request GET /management/login HTTP/1.1
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,507] DEBUG {MainClientExec} - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,509] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /management/login HTTP/1.1
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,509] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,509] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic ****
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,509] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: ****8:9164
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,509] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,510] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.18)
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,510] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,510] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /management/login HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,510] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,510] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Basic ****[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,511] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: ****:9164[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,511] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,511] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.18)[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,511] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,511] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,688] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,689] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,690] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS, PATCH[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,690] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 10:07:08 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,691] DEBUG {wire} - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,694] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,694] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,694] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS, PATCH
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,694] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,695] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 10:07:08 GMT
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,695] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,695] DEBUG {headers} - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: Keep-Alive
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,700] DEBUG {MainClientExec} - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,700] DEBUG {HttpAuthenticator} - Authentication required
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,700] DEBUG {HttpAuthenticator} - ****:9164 requested authentication
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,700] DEBUG {HttpAuthenticator} - Response contains no authentication challenges
[2023-04-27 13:07:08,706] DEBUG {DashboardServerExceptionMapper} - Error: org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.exception.ManagementApiException: Unauthorized
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.commons.utils.ManagementApiUtils.getToken(ManagementApiUtils.java:65)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.commons.utils.ManagementApiUtils.getAccessToken(ManagementApiUtils.java:50)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.heartbeat.HeartBeatDelegate.registerNode(HeartBeatDelegate.java:99)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.heartbeat.HeartBeatDelegate.processHeartbeat(HeartBeatDelegate.java:69)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.api.HeartbeatApi.receiveNodeHeartbeat(HeartbeatApi.java:54)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1450)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Also below are open ports on the server

```
1. Micro Integrator:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8253            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17659646   1496906/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8290            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17659641   1496906/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46275           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17659553   1496906/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9201            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17659652   1496906/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9164            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17659657   1496906/java

2. Dashboard:

tcp6       0      0 :::9743                 :::*                    LISTEN      1005       16955092   1446707/java
```

Firewall is off, there are no rules in iptables. Permissions also need to be, because this is the default admin user

Comment: Have you changed the default user name and password of MI?

Comment: The question is not about programming. Please find the relevant stack exchange to re post it and get assistance